# Error mongoose: applyHooks.middlewareFunctions.flatMap is not a function?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, mongoose

I'm trying to run a nodejs project on the UBUNTu 20.04 server. It turns out such an error

> /node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/model/applyHooks.js:28 const
> alreadyHookedFunctions = new
> Set(applyHooks.middlewareFunctions.flatMap(fn => ([fn, `$__${fn}`])));
> ^
>
> TypeError: applyHooks.middlewareFunctions.flatMap is not a function
> at Object. (/opt//node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/model/applyHooks.js:28:71)

version mongod 6.0.4.I also tried to reduce it to 5, still this error comes out

mongo.config file

```
module.exports = async () => {
  mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
  await mongoose
    .connect(config.MONGO_URI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })
    .then(() => {
      logger.info(`MongoDB connected `);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      logger.error('MongoDB NO CONNECT :' + err);
    });
};
```

Comment: What datatype is applyHooks.middlewareFunctions at that point?

Comment: @Joe , I don't know how to look at it? I have a script on nodejs. There is a connection to mongo. Everything works fine for me on windows 10. I want to run on a vps server. OC - ubunty 20. I can't run on ubuntu